# Solr basic auth by collection

Tags: solr, basic-authentication

My question is quite simple but I'm not able to make [Solr Basic Authentication Plugin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/basic-authentication-plugin.html#basic-authentication-plugin) to run as I think it *should* work.

In details : I'm running a single node instance of [Docker Solr 7](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/). I've created two cores, and a "manager" role for each one (using solr API). My `security.json` file look like that

```
{
   "authentication":{
      "blockUnknown":true,
      "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
      "credentials":{
         "solr":"KzdeDy9vIPliG3IsrvZJJt5L8LJQsK+o8fyTQ4g5b8g= rNwIT3FVvt6dqfRTFzNfehMcuGXaG1uipAVVJ71zgXw=",
         "sandbox2":"Yyz547gwtwHBJkWl3AdYn5wUKZX28JMjm5J6pI4enBY= 7idFe+baqhDzjOPR5Q9N3hS/0kCrWoZFdfwEl0zD298=",
         "sandbox1":"b/my6RlkYNzh11MjU8M16aYbcXRCjU9vbXH8kUnuWw4= B3Mpuenz0JtdWlQ5FMg1wv/1TtoJ6n3IILeVhgZvga0="
      },
      "":{
         "v":0
      }
   },
   "authorization":{
      "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
      "permissions":[
         {
            "name":"security-edit",
            "role":"admin",
            "index":1
         },
         {
            "collection":"sandbox2",
            "role":"sandbox2_manager",
            "name":"sandbox2.manager",
            "index":2
         },
         {
            "collection":"sandbox1",
            "role":"sandbox1_manager",
            "name":"sandbox1.manager",
            "index":3
         }
      ],
      "user-role":{
         "solr":"admin",
         "sandbox2":"sandbox2_manager",
         "sandbox1":"sandbox1_manager"
      },
      "":{
         "v":0
      }
   }
}
```

What I want is to *isolate* each cores, aka : only allow `sandbox1` user to use the `sandbox1` core, and only allow `sandbox2` user to use the `sandbox2` core. But with my configuration, I'm still able to query the `sandbox1` core with the `sandbox2` user ... Annoying for a shared SOLR instance !

Can you help me please ?

Bes regards